# In Python, how do I use voidspace to mock out just one method (out of many) of an object?

Tags: python, mocking

e.g.

```
class Foobar:
    def func():
        print('This should never be printed.')
    def func2():
        print('Hello!')

def test_mock_first_func():
    foobar = Foobar()
    # !!! do something here to mock out foobar.func()
    foobar.func()
    foobar.func2()
```

I expect the console to output:

```
 Hello!
```

Comment: Do you not want `func()` to print anything? just replace the print statement with `pass`?

Comment: Well, no, this question is about mocking. Assume the Foobar class has a correct implementation: you should not change its code.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you mean by "mocking"? Just that you want to redirect the output from certain functions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

Specifically, I want the syntax that achieves what I asked using 
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/

Comment: Thanks for your help, Cameron Sparr, I think I found an answer. I'm really just typing-out-loud here. I'm sure the rest of the Internet will appreciate this shortcut to understanding the mocking library.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apparently the documentation just goes around in roundabouts but in fact this page contains the solution:

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#mocking-unbound-methods

To supplement the weak documentation (high on words, low on content... such a shame) that uses confusing variable / function names in the the example, the correct way to mock the method is so:

```
class Foobar:
    def func():
        print('This should never be printed.')
    def func2():
        print('Hello!')

def test_mock_first_func():
    with patch.object(Foobar, 'func', autospec=True) as mocked_function:
        foobar = Foobar()
        foobar.func()  # This function will do nothing; we haven't set any expectations for mocked_function!
        foobar.func2()
```